# Remove observations with missing spatial coordinates (longitude, latitude)

Tags: r, validation, spatial, data-cleaning

I have a data set with several missing spatial coordinates. I am trying to remove those rows with missing spatial coordinates.

```
library(lubridate)
library(amt)

data <- read.csv("gpslocations.csv")
```

Data set looks like this:

```
DATE        TIME        LATITUDE     LONGITUDE 
2012-10-14  19:00:00    50.2526641  -123.232616 
2012-10-14  20:01:00    50.2528844  -123.2286441    
2012-10-14  21:00:00    50.2525354  -123.2314822    
2012-10-14  22:00:00    50.2525936  -123.2311984    
2012-10-14  23:01:00    NA          NA
2012-10-15  0:01:00     NA          NA
2012-10-15  1:01:00     NA          NA
2012-10-15  2:01:00     NA          NA


data_clean <- (!is.na('LATITUDE'))
```

I want to remove rows 5-8 but I don't seem to be able to do that. Ideally, I also want to use the pipe function to specify date and time format and then the project in the correct coordinate system. I would appreciate any help with the correct code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`if_all` if helpful here. Your issue is that they are 0, not NA. also, your code is only checking if the string `'LATITUDE'` is na. It is not filtering the dataset.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data |>
  filter(if_all(c(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE), \(x) x != 0))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   DATE       TIME   LATITUDE LONGITUDE
#>   <date>     <time>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 2012-10-14 19:00      50.3     -123.
#> 2 2012-10-14 20:01      50.3     -123.
#> 3 2012-10-14 21:00      50.3     -123.
#> 4 2012-10-14 22:00      50.3     -123.
```

or another option if you want to stay in base:

```r
data[apply(data[,c("LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE")] != 0, 1, any),]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   DATE       TIME   LATITUDE LONGITUDE
#>   <date>     <time>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 2012-10-14 19:00      50.3     -123.
#> 2 2012-10-14 20:01      50.3     -123.
#> 3 2012-10-14 21:00      50.3     -123.
#> 4 2012-10-14 22:00      50.3     -123.
```

EDIT

Everything should be the same if they are NA and not 0 if you just change to !is.na:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data[apply(!is.na(data[,c("LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE")]) , 1, any),]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   DATE       TIME   LATITUDE LONGITUDE
#>   <date>     <time>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 2012-10-14 19:00      50.3     -123.
#> 2 2012-10-14 20:01      50.3     -123.
#> 3 2012-10-14 21:00      50.3     -123.
#> 4 2012-10-14 22:00      50.3     -123.

data |>
  filter(if_all(c(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE), \(x) !is.na(x)))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   DATE       TIME   LATITUDE LONGITUDE
#>   <date>     <time>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 2012-10-14 19:00      50.3     -123.
#> 2 2012-10-14 20:01      50.3     -123.
#> 3 2012-10-14 21:00      50.3     -123.
#> 4 2012-10-14 22:00      50.3     -123.
```

Comment: Thank you AndS. I just edited my table as the missing spatial values are blank in the .csv file and show up as 'NA' and not 0 in R. The second option seems to work, however, there are more rows that are removed than necessary. When I remove rows in the .csv file, they are many more remaining rows however with your second code which works, there are a lot less rows. I just want the blank rows (that show NA in R) to be removed. Please can you help with the correct code. Thank you so much, appreciate your help and time.

Comment: I updated my response. Can you give me an example of a row being removed that should not?

Comment: So in ArcPro I have a total of 244,670 GPS locations and when I remove them there, I get 227,235 GPS locations. However, in R, I get a message saying Omitted 227176 rows, which should not be the case.

Comment: I'm not sure were the message is coming from. The code above should not give you any messages about omitting rows.

Comment: Yeah, and that is what I am also confused about. The numbers do not match up, so I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: are you reading a shapefile or a csv?

Comment: Reading a .csv file, but just so you know the data set has a number of other columns too which I also want to get rid of eventually. Does that make a difference? All I want to do is remove rows with no values in the columns LATITUDE and LONGITUDE. It should not be that difficult and I am not sure why I am having such a tough time.  Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: I think your issue is actually reading the csv not filtering the data. try `readr::read_csv`

Comment: Thank you but sadly no, now the rows are not even getting removed. If there is any chance I can email you or you email that would be really awesome, but totally understand if not possible. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249873/discussion-between-ands-and-eleman).